# Which is better - epoxy or polyurethane to fix the hairline cracks on the basement wall that is leaking?

Tags: basement

Which is better - epoxy or polyurethane to fix the hairline cracks on the basement wall that is leaking? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: My opinion neither will fix a leaking wall from the inside, once that spot is fixed a new location will start leaking.  The only real way is to eliminate the water through drainage and possibly sealing from the outside.

Comment: @EdBeal copy-paste that into an answer.

Comment: Granted that it might be tough to dig in the winter, but have you taken care of gutters and any other above-ground drainage?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here it is. My opinion neither will fix a leaking wall from the inside, once that spot is fixed a new location will start leaking. The only real way is to eliminate the water through drainage and possibly sealing from the outside.

Comment: Thank you. During the winter time, no one wants to dig holes from outside. None of the companies, even the companies that traditionally works from outside, did not even mention fixing it from outside. They only mention working from inside. One of them told me they would like to put 11 push piers under the concrete wall to lift the foundation. I might consider to fix the problem next spring. Before that, I have to clean the water every time it rains or snows.

Comment: Many homes do work from the inside but it is getting rid of the water not really fixing the leaks. Many company's will install a drain at the wall with a sump to pump the water out. If done on the outside with proper drainage the walls won't leak, even block walls can be dry.